# Diophantine equation $a_1+2a_2+...+na_n=n$

Tags: number-theory

I have to find all non negative integer solutions of $a_1+2a_2+...+na_n=n$

I didn't find any source in which I can at least attempt for a solution.

Do you know some source or algorithm that I can implement in a code?

Comment: See e.g. [SO::Generating the partitions of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400794/generating-the-partitions-of-a-number) for the algorithm/code part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the number of partitions of $n$ denoted $p(n)$ which is sequence [A000041](http://oeis.org/A000041) which has a lot of information and references. For actually producing the solutions there are many ways depending on what you want to use. For example, the first reference in A00041 is to [Matters Computational](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/#fxtbook) by Joerg Arndt. If you want algorithms then that is a computer science problem, but many computer algebra systems have partitions available. The connection of the $a_i$ to a partition is that $a_i$ is the number of parts of size $i$ in the partition.

Comment: Not the number of partiotions. I need an algorithm to generate the solutions

Comment: So, for a given n I will have several sets of solutions

Comment: Yes, and if you want to get all partitions, many computer algebra systems implement that already. For PARI/GP use "forpart()". For Mathematica use "IntegerPartitions[]".

Comment: I understand  thank you